# Дописывание в файл новых элементов

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Есть онлайн журнал, из которого по API берутся данные и записываются в файл.
Подскажите, как реализовать функционал записи в файл только отсутствующих элементов?
Есть файл 1.txt с содержимым

```
Март 15 Журнал Версия:1|11Б|действие=Присутствие|ФИО=Иванов_Иван_Иванович внес=староста
Март 15 Журнал Версия:1|11Б|действие=Присутствие|ФИО=Петров_Петр_Петрович внес=староста
```

По API забираются данные:

```
Март 15 Журнал Версия:1|11Б|действие=Присутствие|ФИО=Иванов_Иван_Иванович внес=староста
Март 15 Журнал Версия:1|11Б|действие=Присутствие|ФИО=Петров_Петр_Петрович внес=староста
Март 15 Журнал Версия:1|11Б|действие=Присутствие|ФИО=Александров_Александр_Александрович внес=староста
```

В файл 1.txt должна дописаться только инфа об Александров_Александр_Александрович (ФИО - ключевое поле, по которому должно происходить сравнение в независимости от других полей).
Понимаю, что нужно для начала прочитать 1.txt, но не понимаю, как реализовать проверку имеющихся данных и их сравнение с теми, что забираются по API.

Код скрипта, забирающего по API (пока только полная перезапись файла):

```
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning) # отключаем варнинги
headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'APIKEY_DEFAULT',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
} # прописали хидеры

response = requests.get('https://192.168.100.10/stud/exportModule/stud_export/1', headers=headers, verify=False) #загрузка всех учащихся 
file = open('/home/1.txt','w') #создаем файл для записи результатов
file.write(response.text) #записываем результат
file.close() #закрываем файл
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению  ваш пример с get-запросом у меня не работает, поэтому не понятно, в каком виде вам приходит ответ, но допустим ответ вы преобразовали в список однотипных строк, по формату таких же, как и в записываемом файле, тогда можно действовать  так:

```py
list_fio_result = []
with open('/home/1.txt',encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for str_fio in file:
        fio_file = str_fio.split("ФИО=")[1].split(" внес=")[0]
        list_fio_result.append(fio_file)
    for str_fio in response:
        fio_resp = str_fio.split("ФИО=")[1].split(" внес=")[0]
        if fio_resp not in list_fio_result:
            with open('/home/1.txt', mode="a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
                file.write("\n"+str_fio)
```